# What tools from quantum information can we use to detect the ergodic to many body localization phase trasnsition?

Tags: quantum-information, many-body, anderson-localization

So is there any specific quantity which depends on the density matrix of the excited eigenstates can detect the ergodic to MBL phase transition? Can anything other than half chain entanglement entropy be considered to be important information for detecting the phase transition? Is there any universality class for the eth-mbl transition?